# ГРАММАТИЧЕСКАЯ ОШИБКА

Tags: грамматика

Какая грамматическая ошибка есть в предложении "Кроме рисования я еще пою"?

Comment: @irina19, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка связана с нарушением управления.

Обороты с предлогами кроме, помимо, наряду с, имеющие значение "вместе с", должны обязательно управляться глаголом, имеющим при себе ещё одно существительное, иначе разрушается грамматическая связь в предложении, например:

Можно сказать:  
Кроме сестры, я люблю ещё и брата. (то есть люблю и сестру, и брата)
Помимо хоккея, я увлекаюсь плаванием. (то есть увлекаюсь хоккеем и плаванием)

Нельзя сказать:
Кроме рисования, я ещё пою.
Помимо спорта, я хожу в кино.

Answer (score 2):

*Кроме рисования, я еще пою.*
В предложении упомянуты два действия, но одно из них (пение) представлено глаголом *пою*, а второе (рисование) - отглагольным существительным, что выглядит несколько шероховато. Чтобы сгладить это впечатление, можно слегка распространить обе части высказывания : 
*Кроме рисования всякого рода пасхальных открыток, я еще пою по воскресеньям в церковном хоре*.
В этом случае слово *рисование* максимально приближено к смыслу реального **действия**, а не к названию школьного предмета "рисование".

> А. А. Игнатьев. Пятьдесят лет в строю. Кн. 4 (1947-1953)
> Как всякая лютеранка, она кроме пения по воскресным дням соответствующих псалмов была обязана «делать добрые дела» и никому, например, не отказывать в рекомендации.

Comment: Но в ответах (ЕГЭ) стоит такая формулировка:  ошибка, связанная с неправильным употреблением предлога...

Comment: >> ошибка, связанная с неправильным употреблением предлога...
Мда... Формулировчка оставляет желать. Употребили, значит предлог)))   
Но по большому счету даже в таком случае не факт, что "употребление предлога" - ошибка грамматическая.

Comment: Т.е. здесь предлог "кроме" употреблен неправильно? Я правильно понял?

Answer (score 1):

Предложение, в котором нарушена синтаксическая связь между управляющим словом и зависимым оборотом, имеющим в своем составе предлог "кроме".

Этот оборот, как правило, управляется сказуемым, при котором имеется **однородное по смыслу** **другое управляемое слово**, например: ***кроме книг, выпускают брошюры.***

Кроме рисования, я занимаюсь пением.

Comment: >Этот оборот, как правило, управляется сказуемым,   
  
Но ведь отступления от "как правило" не есть ***грамматическая*** ошибка? Если есть нормативные исключения, значит эти исключения - не ошибка?!

Answer (score 1):

Грамматической не вижу.
Вижу небольшую стилистическую, но далеко не очевидную.

Лучше бы сказать "я еще занимаюсь пением", тогда вроде как занятия рисованием и пением становятся в один ряд - и стилистика улучшается.

Answer (score 1):

"Кроме рисования**,** я еще пою."  Обороты с предлогом "кроме" обычно выделяются запятыми.

Comment: Тоже не факт, что обязательно. Но даже если так, это ошибка пунктуационная, не грамматическая.

Answer (score 0):

Привожу пояснение (спасибо его автору), когда-то найденное мною при изучении вопроса управления:

"При всей кажущейся простоте прием схематизации синтаксических связей в предложениях, составляющих сложное синтаксическое целое, дает возможность установить и проанализировать правильность грамматических форм и всей структуры предложения. Если этот прием станет привычным, превратится в устойчивый навык, то работа редактора над языком и стилем станет более эффективной. Приведем типичный случай использования приема схематизации и обнаружения нормативно-стилистической ошибки в построении предложения.

Недавние гастроли театра «Ла Скала» в Москве, помимо их художественного значения, стали своего рода увертюрой к римским встречам на высшем уровне. 
Прибегнем к схематизации: 1) Гастроли стали увертюрой; 2) Гастроли (какие?) недавние; 3) Гастроли (кого? чего?) театра «Ла Скала» (название образует со словом театр неразложимый оборот); 4) Гастроли (где?) в Москве; 5) Стали (помимо чего?) помимо значения.

Именно здесь и допущена грубая стилистическая ошибка, т.к. обособленный оборот помимо их художественного значения зависит в данном предложении от глагола-сказуемого стали, который управляет творительным падежом: кем-чем?, а слово значение зависит от другого глагола, с другим управлением: иметь (что?) значение. Вариант правки: Недавние гастроли театра «Ла Скала» в Москве не только имели большое художественное значение, но и стали своего рода увертюрой к римским встречам на высшем уровне".